# Why don't I have to make malloc for my const variables?

Tags: c

I'm working on this command shell program and I wonder why I use malloc in one place and not the others? I use malloc for the `tmp`variable, why not for the other variables? Why is it that one variable needs dynamic memory and not the others?

```
struct command
{
    const char **argv;
};

int
spawn_proc (int in, int out, struct command *cmd)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0)
    {
        if (in != 0)
        {
            dup2 (in, 0);
            close (in);
        }

        if (out != 1)
        {
            dup2 (out, 1);
            close (out);
        }

        return execvp (cmd->argv [0], (char * const *)cmd->argv);
    }

    return pid;
}

int
fork_pipes (int n, struct command *cmd)
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    int in, fd [2];

    /* The first process should get its input from the original file descriptor 0.  */
    in = 0;

    /* Note the loop bound, we spawn here all, but the last stage of the pipeline.  */
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        pipe (fd);

        /* f [1] is the write end of the pipe, we carry `in` from the prev iteration.  */
        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], cmd + i);

        /* No need for the write and of the pipe, the child will write here.  */
        close (fd [1]);

        /* Keep the read end of the pipe, the next child will read from there.  */
        in = fd [0];
    }

    /* Last stage of the pipeline - set stdin be the read end of the previous pipe
       and output to the original file descriptor 1. */
    if (in != 0)
        dup2 (in, 0);

    /* Execute the last stage with the current process. */
    return execvp (cmd [i].argv [0], (char * const *)cmd [i].argv);
}

int
main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("in main...");
    int i;

    if (argc == 1) {
        const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };

        struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {sort}, {less} };
        return fork_pipes (3, cmd);
    }
    if (argc > 1) {
        char *tmp;

    // Compute required buffer length
    int len = 1; // adds 1 to the length to account for the \0 terminating char
    for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
      len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2; // +2 accounts for length of "\\|"
    }

    // Allocate buffer
    tmp = (char*) malloc(len);
    tmp[0] = '\0';
    // Concatenate argument into buffer
    int pos = 0;
    for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
      pos += sprintf(tmp+pos, "%s%s", (i==1?"":"|"), argv[i]);
    }

    printf("tmp:%s", tmp);
    fflush(stdout); // force string to be printed

        const char *printenv[] = { "printenv", 0};
        const char *grep[] = { "grep", "-E", tmp, NULL};

        const char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        const char *less[] = { "less", 0 };

        struct command cmd [] = { {printenv}, {grep}, {sort}, {less} };
        return fork_pipes (4, cmd);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variables in particular are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other pointers point to constant values, the data is already put into memory by the compiler. You cannot change them or the data they point to (the data is literal and resides in read-only memory block). The tmp variable will point into a mutable part of memory so you need to allocate it as such.

Of course you could allocate the memory statically so that you wouldn't need malloc for that either, but dynamic allocations are, as the name says, dynamic so you can allocate whatever amount you need defined run time and nor compile time. Like in this case, the amount of memory is not known while compiling.